# Why does VS2015 allow C# 6.0 functions for .Net 4.5.2 applications?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, c#-6.0

I'm getting a strange behavior in Visual Studio 2015. I'm writting an application targeting 4.5.2 .Net Framework:

[image: .Net version]

Then in the application, I try use some things which were implemented in C# 6.0 (which is from .Net 6.0) :

```
int number = 456;
var name = nameof(number);
string str = $"Time = {DateTime.Now}";
```

I'm quite sure that `nameof` and string formatting using `$` are only available in .Net 4.6, but still I'm able to compile this code - event though I'm targeting 4.5.2.

I've run the same code in Visual Studio 2013, also targeting the 4.5.2 version, but this time I can't compile the code (`nameof` not found).

How is it possible, that VS2015 allowed me to compile the code which shouldn't be allowed in target .Net Framework version?

My shoot in the dark is that the VS2015 is capable of computing the C# 6.0 code into the CIL which is still compatible with previous versions, but I'm not sure if it's the right guess.

Comment: Until I find the duplicate the *language* isn't tied to the *framework*. Only VS 2015 supports C# 6

Comment: The duplicate was the very first related answer

Comment: "Only VS 2015 supports C# 6 " - that is wrong @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: dotNET library determines what classes you can use, IDE (as it includes a compiler) determines what language features you can use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# 6 is a new version of language C#, it **has nothing to do** with .NET Framework version. So you can use C# 6 even with old version's of .NET. [Roslyn compiler](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/) is a new compiler that is shipped with VS2015, but [could be installed on older versions of VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847162/using-roslyn-compiler-with-visual-studio-2013) as standalone. So basically Roslyn compiles the new features for you, regardless the framework version you are using.